# Do all HTC One X's use the same screen?

Tags: screen, htc-one-x

I'm going to replace the screen on my HTC One X, but I'm nervous of buying the wrong LCD assembly (I did that with a version of the iPhone 4 before).

Somehow no one seems to have an answer for this - do all versions of the HTC One X use the same screen assembly? My serial starts with HT23, and not the GS23 that so many eBay advertisers have in their description.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are the same.  The one x and x+ use identical display and digitizer.  Buy the assembly the digitizer is adhered tightly to the lcd.